# Stream screen contents to hdmi out?

Tags: android

I have an Evo which has an HDMI out port. The photo gallery and video app can send screen contents out.

I was hoping that it would also send the screen out in all cases - for example, looking at the homescreen would still stream out to hdmi. This does not work.

Is it possible to add this to our app? Interested in demo purposes. Would love to hook the evo up to the projector and stream the screen contents out. Probably not, but just curious,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a cool program called [HDMwIn](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teamwin.hdmi&hl=en) on the android market. Have you tried that out?

Comment: I haven't but will give it a shot once I root my Evo. THanks for the tip, have you used this yourself?

Comment: I have not used it myself. I don't have an EVO. Looks legit though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add this to our app?

Not without hacking some firmware, and possibly not even then.

**UPDATE**: just saw @Kurtis Nusbaum's answer -- looks like root would be sufficient.

> Interested in demo purposes. Would love to hook the evo up to the projector and stream the screen contents out.

Honeycomb tablets support this -- I have used the XOOM and Galaxy Tab that way. The XOOM has a micro HDMI port built in; the Tab 10.1 needs a proprietary adapter thingy.

The DROID Incredible supports composite output of everything, which is supported by more projectors, though it is not especially crisp.

Comment: Ok I will try both those tablets too. I haven't seen a droid incredible, seems like a viable option too if I can get one. Thanks!

Comment: One follow up - a video camera is another option for me, but cannot find a recommendation for one. Anyone use something like this?

Comment: I have used a Webcam suspended over a device before. Working out the rig to actually do the suspending took a bit of fussing with various clamps. You'd then have the Webcam display on a notebook or desktop, which in turn is attached to your projector.

Comment: Cool, will try that too. The Xoom does hdmi out ok, but it seems to force you into landscape mode, not sure if that can be changed. Just a heads up if anyone else is trying this.